# How to fix - unexpected output using getchar() and do-while

Tags: c, if-statement, do-while, logical-operators, getchar

I am trying to make a simple code that will read a char from input and execute "Correct" or "Incorrect input" and run the code again until the correct input is entered. First of all it does not work for capital X. The other issue that I want to fix is that after the incorrect input I have to press enter to get the "Enter x" message, instead of getting in immediately after the incorrect input message.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
         do
         {
            printf("Enter x\n");
            if (getchar()=='x'|| getchar()=='X')
            {
            printf("Entered char is X\n");
            return 0;
            }
            else
            {
            printf("Input incorrect! Please try again!!!\n");
            }
         }
         while (getchar()!='x' || getchar()!='X');
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `if (getchar()=='x'|| getchar()=='X')` This gets __two__ characters. You want: `if ((c=getchar())=='x'|| c=='X')`

Comment: Note also that after the user entered the letter and pressed enter, the input contains two characters: the letter and a `\n`.

Comment: Thank you very much for quick reply Paul!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you hit the `ENTER` key the newline character `\n` is placed in input buffer. You need to consume that newline character in order to read the next character.
Also you are reading two time, which is unnecessary in this case. So your code should be like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
         char inp;
         do
         {
            printf("Enter x\n");
            inp = getchar();
            getchar(); // reading the newline character '\n'
            if (inp == 'x'|| inp =='X')
            {
               printf("Entered char is X\n");
               return 0;
            }
            else
            {
               printf("Input incorrect! Please try again!!!\n");
            }
         }
         while (inp !='x' || inp !='X');
     return 0;
 }
```

> p.s There is no need to put condition checking in while loop, since you are returning in if condition. `while(true)` would work fine. Thanks @bruno for pointing that out.

Comment: please explain the necessity of the do-while ? in case _return_ doesn't works ? ^^

Comment: @bruno There is in fact no necessity of the do-while condition checking. I wanted the code to be as close as possible to the OP code. Although leaving the condition doesn't make the code wrong. while(true) should work just fine.

Comment: warning you cannot detect the EOF using a _char_ for _inp_, and you *hope* the second char is a newline ;-)

Comment: @bruno EOF character is generally Ctrl+Z on windows and Ctrl+D in unix like system. By the looks of OP's code, I believe ENTER ('\n') is the key he is pressing after every input. Your warning is duly noted but I believe that he will not be reaching an EOF character at all. He is a beginner as he mentioned, I will not try to complicate things for him.

Comment: @bruno Usually you will get an EOF character returning from getchar() when your standard input is other than console (i.e., a file). He is reading from a console, so no need for a EOF check.

Comment: _stdin_ can be redirect to read in a file, a on a _pipe_ etc, if this is the case without detecting the EOF you will loop without ending

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the input in a variable, otherwise you keep asking for input several times in a row, for each `getchar` call.

For weird historic reasons, `getchar` actually returns an `int`, since the value `EOF` that can be returned from it is an `int`. So the variable must be `int`.

And finally, each time the user hits enter, a invisible line feed character `\n` is appended to the input stream. This character does you no good, so you should discard it with an extra read.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  int input;

  do
  {
    printf("Enter x\n");
    input = getchar();
    getchar(); // extra getchar to chew up line feed from stdin

    if (input=='x'|| input=='X')
    {
      printf("Entered char is X\n");
    }
    else
    {
      printf("Input incorrect! Please try again!!!\n");
    }
  } while (input!='x' && input!='X'); 

  return 0;
}
```

Please note that the opposite of `input=='x'|| input=='X'` is `input!='x' && input!='X'` (De Morgan's laws). "If input is not 'x' and input is not 'X' then loop".

Comment: why the `while (input!='x' || input!='X');` ? you already know it is false because of the return when x or X is enter. why the second _getchar_ and how can you suppose the user enter a newline just after the first char ?

Comment: @bruno Because the OP is obviously a beginner trying to figure out how loops work. I didn't change their code much not to confuse them. It should be && though, it's a bug inherited from the original code.

Comment: so you consider to repeat the tests is a good way to help the OP to learn ? sorry but I strongly disagree ;-)

Comment: @Lundin and if I may ask, how do I make it execute agan without do-while if the input is incorrect. Thanks for your previous answers, much appreciated!

Comment: @BajroSlatina The only sensible way to achieve that is to use a loop. `while`,  `do while` or `for`.

Answer (score -2):

In your code:

```
if (getchar()=='x'|| getchar()=='X')
```

getchar() is called twice.

Instead, you should write it this way:

```
char c = getchar();
if (c=='x'|| c=='X')
```

for the second part, if your goal is print the message on a new line, then just simply change your printf to:

```
printf("\nInput incorrect! Please try again!!!\n");
```

Comment: for the second part, if your goal is print the message on a new line, then just simply change your printf to:             printf("\nInput incorrect! Please try again!!!\n");

Comment: Change `char c` for `int c` so `EOF` can be detected.

Comment: It should be done if you want to read from file. Not needed for user input.